# Install Gnome 3.10 ubuntu 14.04

Tags: gnome, software-center, software-installation

I heard that gnome 3.10 will be available in Ubuntu 14.04 but when I looked in the software centre gnome 3.8 was offered.Is there a way to install gnome 3.10 without adding ppa in Trusty?

**Edit**

I tried installing through the terminal and gnome 3.10 was installed (gnome shell and desktop).I cheked inside the software centre and gnome wasn't marked as installed.

Comment: Version 3.10 is available for Trusty, what are you looking at in the Software Center? http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/gnome-shell

Comment: 14.04 includes GNOME 3.10. GNOME is a lot of applications.